# php unable to connect sqlite db error 500

Tags: php, sqlite

hi i'm trying to run this code to connect with my db.sqlite database file,
but the server respond with

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**
and the page is blank.

here's my code:

```
<?php

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
     function __costruct()
       {
          $this->open('copiaDatabase.sqlite');
       }

}

$db = new MyDB();
echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
?>
```

Comment: Please add some log files or errors to debug the code

Comment: Sorry i'm new in php, where i can see log file?

Comment: see this link https://davidwinter.me/enable-php-error-logging/ for php logs and if you are running on apache then log files are located at /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: It should be `__construct()` instead of `__costruct()`.

Comment: thanks a lots for your answer i resolve....great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentionned in my comment, you have a typo:

It should be `__construct()` instead of `__costruct()`.